# How to send lan traffic to bypass the vpn for android

Tags: vpn, router, wifi, local-area-network

How to send lan traffic to bypass the vpn, for that network 192.168.3.0/24 directly appealed to the wifi router, and do not through the VPN

Comment: It can be done using routing. In a proper setup all your traffic should not go through vpn. But it depends on your setup. How is the network configured? What is the default gateway and routing look like?

Comment: Down voted due to being way  too broad. Really need to know what your using for the Vpn device

Comment: @Nath vpn device is on android

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows

1. Open network connections
2. Open settings of VPN connection
3. Go to Networking TAB
4. Go to TCP/IP - Settings
5. In Advanced disable: Use default gateway on remote network.